# CachingConnectionFactory or DelegatingConnectionFactory

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jms, spring-jms

I've been doing some research([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022181/prevent-use-of-cachingconnectionfactory-with-defaultjmslistenercontainerfactory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808386/should-i-or-shouldnt-i-use-the-cachingconnectionfactory-with-hornetq-2-4-1) and etc.) and with some experience I have follwing feeling about the choice between the two, it seems like:

**CachingConnectionFactory** is for simple container that don't have much of messaging transaction management(like Tomcat with ActiveMQ), so that the `caching` part can guarantee some level of performance even if Spring by nature have to start a new session/connection/producer to each transmission, so the same connection/session get cached to reuse and avoid overhead by extending `SingleConnectionFactory`.

**DelegatingConnectionFactory** is for mature application server so that the CF/transaction management is in the hand of the server(Websphere MQ, JBoss HornetQ etc) so that this CF plays as a delegation and leaves the workload to the server. So the actual performance depends on how to tune up app server's CF and queue and transaction management.

I may be too drunk to make this up so please correct me if above does not make sense. I have one more question base on this comparison that, if Spring `JmsTemplate` by nature have to open/close session and all to each transmission, then how we can improve the performance by utilize the `JmsTemplate` with the app server's jms management?