# Issue with CachingConnectionFactory and DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, ibm-mq, spring-jms

It is mentioned in the documentation of `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` class that it is not  recommended to use `CachingConnectionFactory` with dynamic scaling. While searching, I have encountered  following link:

[Why DefaultMessageListenerContainer should not use CachingConnectionFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984319/why-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-should-not-use-cachingconnectionfactory/21989895#21989895)

Here found a comment from Gary Russell that

> the problem is with caching consumers when using variable concurrency in the container; we can end up with a live consumer "stuck" in the cache".

We have used `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` and `CachingConnectionFactory` together so this is surely a problem from above link.

We are encountering problems with our application having following behaviour:

- TCP ZeroWindow network congestion
- TCP RESET from application server to MQ
- DB connection grows during the issue while different transactions halt
- Messages in certain queues gets built up

We have following code configuration :

1. In ibmmq-context.xml file:

   ```
   <!-- WebSphere MQ Connection Factory -->
   <bean id="appMqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory">
      <property name="hostName">
          <value>${ibmmq.ip}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="port">
          <value>${ibmmq.port}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="queueManager">
          <value>${ibmmq.queuemanager}</value>
      </property>
      <property name="channel"> 
   <value>${ibmmq.channel}</value> 
   </property>
      <property name="clientReconnectOptions"> 
   <util:constant static-field="com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_RECONNECT"/> 
   </property>
   <property name="transportType" ref="appTransport"/>
   </bean>

   <!-- A cached connection  -->
       <bean id="appCachedConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
           <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="appMqConnectionFactory"/>
           <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="${jms.session.cachesize}"/>
       </bean>

       <!--  Use native MQ classes. -->
   <bean id="appTransport" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean">
   <property name="staticField">
   <value>com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP</value>
   </property>
   </bean>
   ```
2. In jms-context file:

   ```
   <bean id="bankListener"  class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachedConnectionFactory" />
     <property name="destination" ref="transactionResponseDestination" />
     <property name="messageListener" ref="thirdpartyService" />
     <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
     <property name="taskExecutor" ref="listenerExecutor"/>
     <property name="concurrency" value="20-30"/>
   </bean>
   ```

There are 6 such listeners like bankListener and each of the listeners has concurrency value, varies from 10-40

```
<bean id="listenerExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
  <property name="maxPoolSize" value="140"/>
  <property name="corePoolSize" value="100"/>
  <property name="queueCapacity" value="30"/>
  <property name="threadNamePrefix" value="jms-listener-task-"/>
  <property name="threadGroupName" value="jms-listener-tasks"/>
</bean>
```

and `jms-context.xml` file uses `ibmmq-context.xml` file.

3. And to note, we have used IBM MQ 7.1, Spring 4.2.8, spring-integration-core as 4.3.1.RELEASE  and JBoss EAP 6.4.10

We are planning to fix this by following way:

```
<bean id="bankListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="appMqConnectionFactory" />
  <property name="destination" ref="transactionResponseDestination" />
  <property name="messageListener" ref="thirdpartyService" />
  <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
  <property name="taskExecutor" ref="listenerExecutor"/>
  <property name="concurrency" value="20-30"/>
</bean>
```

My request:

1. Please review the configuration and let me know is there anything else to be changed.
2. Could you please also explain our application behaviour(above 4 points - a to d) with our current configuration with `CachingConnectionFactory` and `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: did you get the solutiobn>?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

```
cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(false);
```

Or in Spring it should be:

```
<bean id="appCachedConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    ...
    <property name="cacheConsumers" value="false"/>
    ...
</bean>
```