# Why is Spring JMS creating a JMS connection every second when connecting to an ActiveMQ Broker?

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I've created a Spring JMS application using version 4.1.2.RELEASE, which is connected to a broker that is running ActiveMQ 5.11.0. The problem that I'm seeing is as follows. In the logs, I notice that every second, I'm seeing a connection being created as such.

2017-06-21 13:10:21,046 | level=INFO | thread=ActiveMQ Task-1 | class=org.apache.activemq.transport.failover.FailoverTransport | Successfully connected to tcp://localhost:61616

I know that it is creating a new ActiveMQ connection each time, because it says successfully "connected" and not "reconnected" as shown in the code located here: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.collector/1.3.3/org/apache/activemq/transport/failover/FailoverTransport.java#891

I don't have a caching connection factory set for my consumer, but I'm wondering if the following is the culprit when it comes to why I'm seeing constant connections being created.

```
factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);
```

The following post states that consumers should not be cached, but I wonder if that applies to caching the connection + session. If the connection is cached, but the session is not, then I wonder if that creates a problem.

[Why DefaultMessageListenerContainer should not use CachingConnectionFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984319/why-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-should-not-use-cachingconnectionfactory/21989895#21989895)

The following are the configurations that I'm using in my application. I am hoping that it is something that I've misconfigured, and would appreciate any insights that anyone has to offer.

**Spring Configurations**

```
@Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() throws Throwable {
DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());

        factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);
        factory.setMaxMessagesPerTask(-1);
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
        return factory;
}

@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(){
CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheConsumers(false);
cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(1);
return cachingConnectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(1000L);
redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(1000L);
redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(6);
redeliveryPolicy.setUseExponentialBackOff(true);
redeliveryPolicy.setBackOffMultiplier(5);
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQ = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "admin", "tcp://localhost:61616");
activeMQ.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
activeMQ.setPrefetchPolicy(prefetchPolicy());
return activeMQ;
}

@Bean
public JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate(){
ActiveMQTopic activeMQ = new ActiveMQTopic("topic.out");
JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate = new JmsMessagingTemplate(cachingConnectionFactory());
jmsMessagingTemplate.setDefaultDestination(activeMQ);
return jmsMessagingTemplate;
}

protected ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy prefetchPolicy(){
ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy prefetchPolicy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
int prefetchValue = 1000; 
prefetchPolicy.setQueuePrefetch(prefetchValue);
return prefetchPolicy;
}
```

Thanks,

Juan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed the following code.

```
factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_NONE);
```

The moment that I removed it, the rapid connection creation stopped.