# Messages are getting stuck in activemq queue

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

Activemq version: 5.14.3
Java version 1.7

There are 8 consumers for one queue, messages are stuck in some of the consumers.[image: screen shot]

In the above image messages are stuck in dispatched queue of first 4 consumer.
Here is my spring configuration file.

```
       <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="failover:(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61617)?randomize=false"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cachingFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="queue/WebHookProcessingQueue"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myMessageSender" class="com.omoto.jms.sender.MyMessageSender">
        <property name="jmsTemplate">
            <ref bean="jmsTemplate"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

  <bean id="responseJsonMessageListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="cachingFactory"/>
        <property name="destinationName" value="/queue/ResponseJsonProcessingQueue"/>
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="8"/>
        <property name="messageListener" ref="responseJsonServiceListner"/>
    </bean>
```

I am new to activemq, please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

We had similar issue with CachingConnectionFactory with DefaultMessageListenerContainer, the issue is resolved after  removing the CachingConnectionFactory from DefaultMessageListenerContainer. Alternatively you can disable consumer caching from CachingConnectionFactory . Refer this thread for more info [Why DefaultMessageListenerContainer should not use CachingConnectionFactory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984319/why-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-should-not-use-cachingconnectionfactory).