# Spring Integration: How to use SingleConnectionFactory with ActiveMQ?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, activemq-classic, spring-jms

Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE.

With `spring.jms.cache.enabled=true` (default), Spring creates a `CachingConnectionFactory`:

```
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.jms.cache", name = "enabled", havingValue = "true",
            matchIfMissing = true)
    static class CachingConnectionFactoryConfiguration {
```

This is bad since [it shouldn't be used with `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984319/why-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-should-not-use-cachingconnectionfactory). I think it's the reason why some of my messages get "lost" until they suddenly reappear.

With `spring.jms.cache.enabled=false`, Spring creates an `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`:

```
    @ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "spring.jms.cache", name = "enabled", havingValue = "false")
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory(ActiveMQProperties properties,
            ObjectProvider<ActiveMQConnectionFactoryCustomizer> factoryCustomizers) {
        return createJmsConnectionFactory(properties, factoryCustomizers);
    }

    private static ActiveMQConnectionFactory createJmsConnectionFactory(ActiveMQProperties properties,
```

This is bad because with each poll, it creates a new connection to the Broker - flooding my broker with hundreds of connections.

So I though the solution to my problems is to use a `SingleConnectionFactory`. In `AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.MessageListenerContainerResourceFactory` I saw:

```
    public Connection createConnection() throws JMSException {
        if (AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.this.sharedConnectionEnabled()) {
            Connection sharedCon = AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.this.getSharedConnection();
            return new SingleConnectionFactory(sharedCon).createConnection();
        }
```

So I thought I would just:

```
Jms.channel(connectionFactory)
    .cacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONNECTION)
```

but as it turns out, this method is never called, only `JmsAccessor.createConnection()` is which creates an `ActiveMQConnectionFactory`. My cache level has no effect.

So how do I use `SingleConnectionFactory` properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caching factory is only a problem with the DMLC if you have variable concurrency.

Just define a `SingleConnctionFactory` as a `@Bean` and use `Jms.channel(mySingleCF())...`.

**EDIT**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So63120705Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So63120705Application.class, args).close(); // JVM should exit
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory, IntegrationFlowContext context,
            JmsTemplate template) {

        return args -> {
            SingleConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new SingleConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);

            IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.channel(Jms.channel(connectionFactory)
                                .destination("foo"))
                        .handle(System.out::println);

            context.registration(flow)
                .id("jms")
                .addBean(connectionFactory)
                .register();

            template.convertAndSend("foo", "test");
            Thread.sleep(5_000);
        };
    }

}
```

```
spring.jms.cache.enabled=false
```

Comment: Have just tested and it works as expected. Probably you are confused with the `Jms.channel()` nature. Together with the `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` container where that `CACHE_CONNECTION` is applied, it also has a `JmsTemplate` part which is used to send message into JMS. And this one really creates a fresh connection from the factory on its interaction.

Comment: Well, tested with this `Jms.channel(new SingleConnectionFactory(connectionFactory))` and looks like that target `ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection()` is really called only once: `Mockito.verify(this.connectionFactory).createConnection()`

Comment: Thank you so much for your support, Gary. I tried to do what you suggested but I'm not sure how to properly `SingleConnectionFactory` as a bean without also having to create my own `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` and do all the property binding myself. Meanwhile I gave `spring.activemq.pool.enable=true` (with `org.messaginghub:pooled-jms`) a go and it worked. I'll give your solution another try once the time pressure is gone :)

Comment: That is correct; as soon as you define any bean of type `ConnectionFactory`, you are on your own `@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ConnectionFactory.class)`. Unfortunately, while Artem's suggestion works around that problem, it causes another because it's not a `@Bean` and `destroy()` is never called when the context is closed and the JVM doesn't exit. One solution is to register the flow dynamically, which allows you to add it as a bean - see the edit to my answer.