# Camel connecting multiple times to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: java, apache-camel, activemq-artemis

I am using Apache Camel to connect and subscribe to ActiveMQ Artemis feeds and forward to Kafka topics.

It runs fine for a while, but then stops with an exception:
`jakarta.jms.JMSSecurityException: username 'x...@yy.com' has too many connections`

So clearly there's something in the way Camel works that ActiveMQ Artemis, or some security settings on that side of the connection, doesn't like. I know that the feed I'm connecting to does have some checks in place to prevent applications from connecting and disconnecting multiple times in quick succession; so I think I'm hitting that.

Looking into it, it appears that camel reconnects and pulls regularly, rather than creating a single connection (or even a single connection per Camel Route); and so I think this is causing the broker to kick me out.

Has anyone else come across this? Any ideas?

Code for reference:

```java
ActiveMQComponent amqComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
amqComponent.setUsername(amqUser);
amqComponent.setPassword(amqPassword);
amqComponent.setClientId("clientID");

ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
cf.setTrustedPackages(List.of("com..."));
cf.setBrokerURL("tcp://" + amqServer + ":" + amqPort + "?jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false");
amqComponent.setConnectionFactory(cf);
//amqComponent.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
//amqComponent.setSubscriptionShared(true);
//amqComponent.setUsePooledConnection(true);
           
context.addComponent("activemq", amqComponent);

//...

from("activemq:topic:" + amqFeedTopic + "?clientId=" + clientid  + "&durableSubscriptionName=" + clientid + "-sub")
                .id(clientid)
                .description("Connection for " + clientid)
                .to("kafka:" + kafkaTopic + "?brokers=" + kafkaBootstrapServers);
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace of any further details associated with the `JMSSecurityException`? The text "has too many connections" doesn't appear in the ActiveMQ Artemis code-base so I don't think it's coming from the broker but rather from somewhere else.

Comment: yeah, I think it's a custom interceptor of some kind on their end that tracks for "spammy users" (literally - `ClientConnectionLimiter.lambda$checkForSpammyUser$0(ClientConnectionLimiter.java:28)`). When I look in Eclipse in debug view I see a thread for the connection flickering in and out of life - so there's definitely some quick opening and closing of connections going on

Comment: If it's a custom interceptor that's enforcing these restrictions then there's not much anybody on Stack Overflow can help with here. You'd have to work directly with the author(s) of the interceptor or the administrators of that service.

Comment: My point is, though, Camel shouldn't be connecting and disconnecting over and over again - it should make a single subscription to the topic and then receive messages. Or even if it does need to poll, it shouldn't disconnect and reconnect each time it wants to do it

Comment: @JustinBertram see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120705/spring-integration-how-to-use-singleconnectionfactory-with-activemq - " with each poll, it creates a new connection to the Broker - flooding my broker with hundreds of connections."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer: [Spring Integration: How to use SingleConnectionFactory with ActiveMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120705/spring-integration-how-to-use-singleconnectionfactory-with-activemq) pointed me in the right direction.

Essentially, the connection factory determines the approach; and the default connection factory will disconnect and reconnect regularly.

*For clarity, it is the Spring JMS code, not the connection factory, that is doing the disconnect and reconnect. In fact, it still does this even when using the solution outlined below. The caching connection factory vends a proxy to Spring JMS and keeps the connection open. Thanks to Doug Grove in the comments for pointing this out.*

To fix this, use a `SingleConnectionFactory` or its subclass, `CachingConnectionFactory` instead.

Now, these can't accept user/password like the standard AMQ one can, and so you need to use a `UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter` to provide those.

Simple, right?

Here's some code:

```java
ActiveMQComponent amqComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
cf.setBrokerURL("tcp://" + amqServer + ":" + amqPort + " jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false");
       
UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter uca = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
uca.setUsername(amqUser);
uca.setPassword(amqPassword);
uca.setTargetConnectionFactory(cf);
            
CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(uca);
ccf.setClientId(amqClientID);
            
amqComponent.setConnectionFactory(ccf);
amqComponent.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
            
context.addComponent("activemq", amqComponent);
```

Note also, with this approach, you can only have one Camel Route using this Caching Connection Factory. If you try to add more than one, you'll get errors on the other routes.

To fix this, you'll need to use a whole new Camel Context for each Route, and configure these connections factories on each.

Comment: For clarity, it is the Spring JMS code, not the connection factory, that is doing the disconnect and reconnect.  In fact, it still does this even when using the caching connection factory.  The caching connection factory vends a proxy to Spring JMS and keeps the connection open.

Comment: Thanks. @DougGrove do you mind if I copy that into the answer somewhere?

Comment: please, feel free.