# org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory provide username and password

Tags: java, activemq-artemis

How do I provide a username and password into a `org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory`? (NOT the rabbit one).

Using Apache Camel, I'm trying the following:

```java
ActiveMQComponent amqComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
//amqComponent.setUsername(amqUser);
//amqComponent.setPassword(amqPassword);
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
cf.setBrokerURL("tcp://" + amqServer + ":" + amqPort + "?jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false");

CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(cf);
ccf.setClientId("clientID");
amqComponent.setConnectionFactory(ccf);

context.addComponent("activemq", amqComponent);
```

If I uncomment the `.setUsername` and `.setPassword` calls, I get an error:

> "SingleConnectionFactory does not support custom username and password"

(because `SingleConnectionFactory` is the parent class for this `CachingConnectionFactory`).

Clearly if I leave the lines commented, I get an authentication error because I'm not providing a user/password.

How can I pass the ActiveMQ credentials when using a `CachingConnectionFactory`?

(as an aside, [Spring Integration: How to use SingleConnectionFactory with ActiveMQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63120705/spring-integration-how-to-use-singleconnectionfactory-with-activemq) discusses why I am trying to use a CCF as opposed to just using the ActiveMQConnectionFactory - "with each poll, it creates a new connection to the Broker - flooding my broker with hundreds of connections")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdaptor`, e.g. as follows:

```java
ActiveMQComponent amqComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
ActiveMQConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
cf.setBrokerURL("tcp://" + amqServer + ":" + amqPort + " jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false");
       
UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter uca = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
uca.setUsername(amqUser);
uca.setPassword(amqPassword);
uca.setTargetConnectionFactory(cf);
            
CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(uca);
ccf.setClientId(amqClientID);
            
amqComponent.setConnectionFactory(ccf);
amqComponent.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
            
context.addComponent("activemq", amqComponent);
```