# How to ensure that JMSTemplate caches consumer i.e. com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver?

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms, jmstemplate

I am facing a scenario where the reply queue I connect to, runs out of handles. I have traced it to the fact that my JMS Producers are being cached but not my JMS consumers. I am able to send and receive messages just fine so there is no problem with connecting-sending-receiving to/from the queues. I am using the CachedConnectionFactory (SessionCacheSize = 10)with the target factory as `com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory` while instantiating the jmsTemplate. Code snippet is as follows

```java
            :
            :
            String replyQueue = "MyQueue";// replyQueue which runs out of handles
            messageCreator.setReplyToQueue(new MQQueue(replyQueue));

            jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(receiveTimeout);
   
            jmsTemplate.send(destination, messageCreator);// Send to destination queue
            Message message = jmsTemplate.receiveSelected(replyQueue, 
                  String.format("JMSCorrelationID = '%s'", messageCreator.getMessageId()));
            :
            :
```

From the logs (jms TRACE is enabled) Producer is cached, so the `destination` queue "handle count" does not increase.

// The first time around (for Producer)

```
Registering cached JMS MessageProducer for destination[queue:///<destination>:com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSender@c9x758b
```

// Second time around, the cached producer is reused

```
Found cached JMS MessageProducer for destination [queue:///<destination>]: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueSender@c9x758b
```

However, the handles for the replyQueue keep increasing because for every call to that queue, I see a new JMS Consumer being registered. Ultimately the calls to open the replyQueue fail because of MQRC_HANDLE_NOT_AVAILABLE

// First time around

```
Registering cached JMS MessageConsumer for destination [queue:///<replyQueue>]:com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@b3ytd25b
```

// Second time around, another MessageConsumer is registered !

```
Registering cached JMS MessageConsumer for destination [queue:///<replyQueue>]:com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueReceiver@re25b
```

Comment: Do you close the replyQ when you are done with it?

Comment: No, I don't. Just like in the case of the MessageProducer, I am expecting JMSTemplate to cache the consumer as well. CacheConsumers property for CachingConnectionFactory is true by default.

Comment: I may have found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21989895/1554876. When I set cacheConsumers=false, the problem goes away. I am still hesitant to put this as an answer because I want to confirm that there isn't another setting which is causing the issue. It is counterintuitive that Producers are cached but cacheConsumers=true (as seen in the question) causes a NEW consumer to be created every time.

Answer (score 1):

My memory is a bit dim on this, but here is what is happening.  You are receiving messages based on a message selector.  This selector is always changing, however.   As a test, either remove the selector or make it a constant and see what happens.  So when you try to cache/pool based on connection/session/consumer, the consumer is always changing.  This requires a new cache entry.

After you go through your 10 sessions, a new connection will be created, but the existing one is not closed.  Increase your session count to 100, for example, and your connection count on the MQ broker should climb 10 time slower.

You need to create a new consumer for every message receive as your correlation ID is always changing.  So just cache connection/session.  No matter what you do, you will always have to round trip to the broker to ask for the new correlation ID.